# How to connect to mySQL with C# using SSH

Tags: c#, java, mysql

My university has given me java string with arguments that I don't understand and can't find online and any way to use.

My question is that the string is for java but i'm using C# with MySql.Data,MySql.Data.Entity to connect to the database. I can access the database with but only from this inside the univerty network.

```
 string str = @"Server=elephant.ecs.westminster.ac.uk;Database=w13XXXXXX;Uid=w13XXXXX;Pwd=XXXXXXXXXX;";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection msc = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(str);
        MySqlCommand command = msc.CreateCommand();
```

But if i want to connect to the database from outside the university i have use SSH the string they have given me is.

```
jdbc:mysql://elephant.ecs.westminster.ac.uk:3306/w1234567_0?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

As you see this for java and im a beginner and dont know to use it with C#

Thanks you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

A good article on this here: [Access MySQL Through SSH Tunnel in a Windows .NET Application](http://georgelantz.com/2007/09/10/access-mysql-through-ssh-tunnel-in-a-windows-net-application/)